# Adding identity column - order of ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the DDL below:

```
create table #test (name varchar(10),dateofbirth datetime)

insert into #test values ('ian', '1976-09-08')
insert into #test values ('maria', '1976-09-08')
```

I realise it is a poor design choice not to have a primary key.  I want to add a new identity column like this:

```
alter table #test add id int identity
```

This works as I would expect i.e. Ian has an ID of 1 and Maria has an ID of 2.

There are 10 million rows in this table.  Can I assume the ID order will respect the order they were entered into the table? e.g. Ian was entered first so he has an ID of 1.  Anne was the millionth row entered so the ID is 1,000,000.

Comment: Is your table heap? No clustered index?

Comment: @lad2025 as stated in the question there is no PK.  I did not design it.

Comment: Why does it matter that the identity order matches the original inserted order? And if it doesn't, how would you know?

Comment: I am tring to figure out when some records were added to the table.  One million were added on day one; another million on day two etc.  It would be good to have a timestap.

Comment: I think the most you can hope for (unless you've got database and transaction log backups and the means to evaluate changes in those) would be to modify your table design to include a datetime field going forwards, and accept that you can't provide this information for anything before the field was added. You can never assume anything on ordering in SQL unless it's made explicit with an ORDER BY. I can't find anything specific to the ordering of a new identity field on an existing table, definitely wouldn't treat it as a safe assumption.

Comment: i think it will, if you feel it is risky then you can take a backup of your table before applying the query , also creating a new table with the same field with an identity column is good idea then insert your data to new table and  remove your old table and rename your new table as old table name, then you can ensure the identity value will be in same order of data insertion

Answer (score 2):

The order in which `IDENTITY` values are assigned to existing rows is undefined.  With your heap example, SQL Server will probably assign values in the physical order of files/pages/slots used to store the rows.  If this matches the order of insertion, it is only by happenstance and should not be relied on.  Space allocation and reuse can cause the physical order of the data to differ from the original order of insertion as may a database with multiple files.

If the table has a clustered index, the values will likely be assigned in order of the clustered index key, but again, don't count on it.  A relational database table is logically an unordered set of rows and should always be treated as such.

If you have an incremental column to derive the insertion order, you can use the `IDENTITY` function in a `SELECT...INTO...ORDER BY` query to create a new table with the identity values assigned in the desired sequence.  Identity values for new rows inserted going forward will be incremental in the order of insertion.